# Disable generate API when DTO is empty nestJS

Tags: typescript, swagger, nestjs

This is my base controller

```
export function BaseControllerFactory<E>(
  createEntityDto: typeof CreateEntityDto,
  updateEntityDto: typeof UpdateEntityDto,
  entityToViewDto: ViewDtoContructor<E>,
): Type<IBaseController<E>> {
  
  class BaseController implements IBaseController<E> {
    constructor(private readonly baseService: BaseService<E>) {}

    @Post()
    @ApiOperation({ summary: 'Create new entity' })
    @ApiBody({ type: createEntityDto })
    async createEntity(@Body(ValidationPipe) dto: Type<CreateEntityDto>) {
      //
    }

    @Get()
    @ApiOperation({ summary: 'Get entities' })
    async getEntities(@Query(ValidationPipe) getEntitiesDto: GetEntitiesDto) {
      //
    }

    ...

  return BaseController;
}
```

And this is UserController extend BaseController

```
@ApiTags('Users')
@Controller('users')
export class UsersController extends BaseControllerFactory<User>(
  CreateUserDto, 
  UpdateUserDto,
  UserToViewDto,
) {
  constructor(private readonly userService: UsersService) {
    super(userService);
  }
}
```

My issue is that when I replace CreateUserDto by null, I want the API create user will be not generated. Thank for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is impossible, DTO only describes the format of the input data, this is not some kind of hard contract.